# Event before loading ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies

I am trying to maintain few objects in cookie to restore some settings. Initially i tried in window.unload to save and restore settings using cookie.It worked in full page load. But it didn't work in my case as whole page is not loading just replacing the specific content using ajax post(ajax load). So can you tell me in which event can i save those values in cookie to restore back while using ajax post ?

I tried the below code in window.unload event

```
window.onunload = function (e) {
    var gridObjModel = $("#Grid");
    var myCookie = escape(JSON.stringify({ 
        "CurrentPage": gridObjModel.pageSettings.currentPage, 
        "SortedColumns": gridObjModel.sortSettings.sortedColumns, 
        "GroupedColumns": gridObjModel.groupSettings.groupedColumns 
    }));
    document.cookie = myCookie;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with the following:

```
$(window).on("unload", function (e) {
    var gridObjModel = $("#Grid");
    var myCookie = escape(JSON.stringify({ 
        "CurrentPage": gridObjModel.pageSettings.currentPage, 
        "SortedColumns": gridObjModel.sortSettings.sortedColumns, 
        "GroupedColumns": gridObjModel.groupSettings.groupedColumns 
    }));
    document.cookie = myCookie;
});
```

When you do a ajax load just trigger unload before:

```
$(window).trigger("unload");
$("#foo").load(someUrl);
```

Comment: Cool. This solutions works well. Thanks much.  Is there no other way instead of triggering 'unload' event?

Comment: @RanjithKumarGovarthanan You could have a custom event, but that just mean you would have to trigger that on `unload` instead, but perhaps that's a better way to implement it. Or did you maybe want it to happen automaicaly when calling `.load`?